# Duda en sintaxis

Tags: php, mysql

Podría alguien decirme porque no funciona num_rows en la segunda oportunidad? ya que la primera vez que lo utilizo funciona y en la segunda me marca un error. La sentencia query pienso que está bien ya que el usuario queda registrado en la base de datos...

dejo el codigo:

```
<?php

    require 'datos_conexion.php';
    session_start();

    // Registrar
    if (isset($_POST["registrar"])) {
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['email']);
        $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['inputPassword']);
        $passEncript = sha1($pass);
        $sqlUser = "SELECT id_user FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
        $resultado = $conexion->query($sqlUser);
        $filas = $resultado->num_rows;
        if ($filas > 0) {
            echo "<script>
                  alert('El email ya fue registrado anteriormente, por favor inicie sesión');
                   window.location= '../expensas.php';
                </script>";
        }else{
            // Insertar información del usuario            
            $sqlUsuario = "INSERT INTO users (Email, Pass) VALUES ('$email','$passEncript')";
            $resultadoUsuario = $conexion->query($sqlUsuario);
            $rows = $resultadoUsuario->num_rows;
            if ($rows > 0) {
                $row = $resultadoUsuario->fetch_assoc();
                $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_user'];
                echo "<script>
                     alert('Se ha registrado correctamente');
                     window.location= '../descarga_expensa.php';
                     </script>";
            }else {
                echo "<script>
                        alert('Error al registrarse');

                     </script>";

            }
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conexion);       

?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar que error te marca?

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\Proyecto Final Administracion\php_logica\registrar.php on line 23

Comment: Cuál de los dos num_rows que ocupas es la línea 23 de tu código para saber la solución?

Comment: El segundo. El que evalúa a $resultadoUsuario...

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que estas intentando obtener el número de filas insertadas con num_rows, para saber cuantas filas se insertaron debes usar `$mysqli->affected_rows`, tu codigo quedaría así:

```php
    <?php

        require 'datos_conexion.php';
        session_start();

        // Registrar
        if (isset($_POST["registrar"])) {
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['email']);
            $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['inputPassword']);
            $passEncript = sha1($pass);
            $sqlUser = "SELECT id_user FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
            $resultado = $conexion->query($sqlUser);
            $filas = $resultado->num_rows;
            if ($filas > 0) {
                echo "<script>
                      alert('El email ya fue registrado anteriormente, por favor inicie sesión');
                       window.location= '../expensas.php';
                    </script>";
            }else{
                // Insertar información del usuario            
                $sqlUsuario = "INSERT INTO users (Email, Pass) VALUES ('$email','$passEncript')";
                $resultadoUsuario = $conexion->query($sqlUsuario);
                //$rows = $resultadoUsuario->num_rows;
                $rows = $conexion->affected_rows;
                if ($rows > 0) {
                    $row = $resultadoUsuario->fetch_assoc();
                    $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id_user'];
                    echo "<script>
                         alert('Se ha registrado correctamente');
                         window.location= '../descarga_expensa.php';
                         </script>";
                }else {
                    echo "<script>
                            alert('Error al registrarse');

                         </script>";

                }
            }
        }

        mysqli_close($conexion);       

    ?>
```

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Aparentemente estaría funcionando, ya que ahora el error se trasladó dos lineas mas abajo...

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Comment: Si, ahora tu problema es que estas intentando obtener la información de un objeto que no es un recurso con datos. sino un true/false.. Debes hacer un select para obtener la información del nuevo usuario. o, obtener los datos de las variables que insertaste.

Comment: Gracias! Intentaré reescribir el código de manera eficaz!

Comment: Si, dentro del `if($rows>0){` puedes obtener los datos del usuario insertado para crear la sesión.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente! funciona perfecto luego de efectuar un nuevo select para el usuario recién registrado!

Comment: Perfecto, si la respuesta te parece válida marcados como aceptada.

Comment: ah! ok! perdón, soy nuevo.

Comment: Por supuesto, un gusto ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, yo no veo necesario que ejecute un nuevo `SELECT`,  yo propongo que guarde desde un iniccio en una variable esa constante, para no tener que hacer un `SELECT` para validar la misma variable. Pienso que haciendo ésto va a saturar mucho su motor de base de datos. Es más, yo propongo que todo lo traiga desde un inicio con una sola consulta, ya que además veo que no es tan complicada, llegando incluso a la conclusión de que hasta es innecesaria la intervención de tanto php para manipular los datos.